# Listview inside listview and issue with height of the nested listview

Tags: android, listview

I have this parent layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center|top"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/parent_listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

and parent_listview's list items have this layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:background="@color/mediumBlue" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sub_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/child_listview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/sub_title" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and child_listview's items have this layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@color/green" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/childName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/childDesc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" >
    </TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I expect to see

```
Parent Layout
   - Parent ListView
             - Parent Item 1
                    -Child item 1
                    -Child item 2
                    -Child item 3
             - Parent Item 2
                    -Child item 1
                    -Child item 2
             - Parent Item 3
                    -Child item 1
             - Parent Item 4
                    -Child item 1
                    -Child item 2
                    -Child item 3
```

but the child listview displays only one item(first item), something like this

```
Parent Layout
   - Parent ListView
             - Parent Item 1
                    -Child item 1
             - Parent Item 2
                    -Child item 1
             - Parent Item 3
                    -Child item 1
             - Parent Item 4
                    -Child item 1
```

if I manually adjust the height of child ListView to say, 250dp, it displays more items but I want the height of the child listview to auto wrap according to the number of items. 
How can I achieve this?
(I have adapters for both listview but I'm not sure if it's relevant for this discussion and hence I'm not including it).

Comment: instead of a listview in a listview, use an expendable listview

Comment: @njzk2 instead of the outer listview or the nested listview or both?

Comment: instead of both. the purpose of an expendable listview is to display a list of lists.

Comment: @njzk2 gotcha! I'll give it a try here and let you know

Comment: @njzk2 worked like charm, thank you.

Comment: @Professor Chaos can you please share the getView() method definition for nested list view

Comment: @Professor Chaos can you please share with us the solution, i have the same issue, thnx.

Answer (score 3):

As a general rule of thumb you should never have a ListView embedded in another ListView. Android isn't fond of embedding scrollable content.

If you really wan't to do what you are describing. You can use (embed) a ListView that aggressively pre-computes it's height based on the contents of the adapter like so:

```
public class ExpandedListView extends ListView {

    public ExpandedListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ExpandedListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(this);
    }

    public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
    Adapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
      if (listAdapter == null)
          return;

      int totalHeight = 0;
      int desiredWidth = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
      for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
          View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
          if (listItem != null) {
            listItem.measure(desiredWidth, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
          }
      }

      ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
      params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
      listView.setLayoutParams(params);
      listView.requestLayout();
    }
}
```

and parent_listview's list items have this layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:background="@color/mediumBlue" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sub_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <com.example.ExpandedListView
        android:id="@+id/child_listview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/sub_title" >
    </com.example.ExpandedListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```